# how to insert an new element into an ArrayField in peewee

Tags: python, postgresql, peewee, flask-peewee

can I user `Model.update(...)` to insert an new element into an ArrrayField in peewee?

What's more, what about JSONField?

Answer (score 0):

Untested, but you could try:

```
MyModel.update(
    arr_field=fn.array_append(
        MyModel.arr_field, 'new value')
).where(MyModel.id == 1)
```